# Alguien me puede asistir para hacer una modificación en un programa para enviar correos en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Estoy modificando un programa que envía correos a todos los empleados. Esta es la interfaz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo le agregué el textbox del asunto y del cuerpo del correo.

Anteriormente se tenia que modificar el asunto y cuerpo desde el código cada que se enviaran correos en esta parte del código.

```
public SmtpConfig getConfig(string company, string asutno, string cuerpo) {
    SmtpConfig conf = new SmtpConfig();
    User u = new User();
    if (company == "003") {
conf.smtp = "";
                conf.port = 777;
                conf.user = "";
                conf.password = "";
                //conf.subject = "Entérate en este correo de mayo 2023";
                conf.subject = "Las noticias de mayo";
                conf.emailAddress = ".com.mx";
                conf.emailName = "noticias@ejemplo.com";
                conf.body = "En este mes se integraran personal al equipo";
                /*conf.body = "*/
```

Ya le asigné el nombre del campo del asunto y del cuerpo en la interfaz.

```
<Label x:Name="label3_Copy" Content="Asunto del correo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,216,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="172"/>
<Label x:Name="label3_Copy1" Content="Cuerpo del correo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,335,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="172"/>
<TextBox x:Name="tbasunto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="79" Margin="42,251,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179" AcceptsReturn="True" Background="#FFFAFAFA"/>
<TextBox x:Name="tbcuerpo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="169" Margin="42,370,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179" AcceptsReturn="True" Background="#FFFAFAFA"/>
```

Haciendo una prueba rápida, comprobé que mis nombres de los campos funcionan correctamente.

```
    if (cbPeriodo.SelectedIndex == 0) {
        MessageBox.Show(tbasunto.Text + tbcuerpo.Text);

        //MessageBox.Show("Debe seleccionar un periodo de nomian");
        return;
    }
```

Lo que tengo que hacer es llevar el valor de los textbox a la parte donde está la configuración del correo y asignarlo a conf.subject y conf.body respectivamente.

Lo que yo intente, es asignarle el valor a la clase Usuario en donde están los getter y setter
justo antes de ejecutar el método sendMail(u)

```
private bool sendEmail(List<User> users, int countEmail, double sleep, BackgroundWorker bl) {
    try
    {
        int count = 1;
        int report = 1;
        eMail mail = new eMail();
        foreach (var u in users)
        {
            //if (u.nEmpleado == "0020359")
            // {
            us.asunto = tbasunto.Text;
            us.cuerpo = tbcuerpo.Text;
            data.sendEmail(u);
```

El metodo sendmail es el siguiente, aquí ejecuto el metodo **getConfig** enviando como parámetro u.compañia, u.asunto y u.cuerpo que se supone que se obtiene el valor de los getters y setters

```
public bool sendEmail(User u)
{
    try
    {
        var dire = u.email.Split('@');
        var s = dire[1].Split('.');

        if (dire[1].Trim().ToLower().Equals("autlook.com.ar") || dire[1].Trim().ToLower().Equals("gmail.com.com") || dire[1].Trim().ToLower().Equals("gmail.com.mx") || dire[1].Trim().ToLower().Equals("hotlive.com") || dire[1].Trim().ToLower().Equals("hotmail.com.mx") || dire[1].Trim().ToLower().Equals("latinchat.com") || dire[1].Trim().ToLower().Equals("latinmail.com") || dire[1].Trim().ToLower().Equals("otlook.com.es") ) {
            string text = u.compañia + ", " + u.tipoNomina + ", " + u.nEmpleado + ", " + u.periodo + ", " + DateTime.Now + ",  correo no valido,  " + u.email; 
            util.createTXT(text, u.txtBlack);
        } else {
            if (u.isSend){
                //if (u.nEmpleado == "0020359") {
                    var conf = getConfig(u.compañia, u.asunto, u.cuerpo);
                    var res = mail.send(u, conf);
```

Para finalmente agregarlo en la parte del armado del correo.

```
    if (company == "003") {
        //conf.smtp = "777";
        conf.smtp = "";
        conf.port = 777;
        conf.user = "";
        conf.password = "";
        //conf.subject = "Entérate en mayo 2023";
        conf.subject = asunto;
        conf.emailAddress = "comuni.com.mx";
        conf.emailName = "nombre de esta planta";
        conf.body = cuerpo;
```

Al compilar y ejecutar el proyecto no me marca errores, solo cuando lleno los datos de asunto y cuerpo para mandar el correo me manda un error en esta parte del código.

```
protected void email_RunCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    if (isSend){
        lblStatus.Content = "Enviado";
        MessageBox.Show("Los Correos se enviaron correctamente");
    }
    else {
        lblStatus.Content = "Enviado";
        MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un error al enviar los correos");
    }
```

El método **email_runComplete** está llamado aquí

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    //if (("25").Text.Equals(""))
    //{
        if (util.isNumber("35")) {
            emailNumber = int.Parse("35");
            if (util.isNumber("5")){
                sleepMin = util.MinToSeconds(int.Parse("5"));
                lUser = util.ConvertGridUser(NominaGrid);
                if (lUser.Count > 0 && lUser != null){

                    //if (!(emailNumber > lUser.Count)) {
                    if (!(emailNumber < lUser.Count)) {
                        btnSend.IsEnabled = false;
                        btnCheck.IsEnabled = false;
                        ProgressLoad.Maximum = lUser.Count;

                        lblSetTime.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        lblTextTime.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                        lblEmailTotal.Content = lUser.Count;
                        bl = new BackgroundWorker();
                        bl.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
                        bl.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                        bl.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(email_DoWork);
                        bl.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(email_progressChanged);
                        bl.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(email_RunCompleted);
```

Se muy poco de C# y la verdad no se en dónde podría meter los valores de asunto y cuerpo.
Si alguien me puede ayudar, se los agradecería mucho.

Saludos.

Comment: De donde sale la variable `us` ??  no debería ser `u` ?? https://i.stack.imgur.com/RndYf.png

Comment: No creo, porque comenzando el método recibo como argumento User u que es la instancia de los getters y setters

public bool sendEmail(User u)
{

Comment: No estas entendiendo, el código que te digo está antes del sendEmail

Comment: Ya lo cambié, pero sigue el mismo error

Comment: Le estas cargando la informacion a otra clase que nada que ver.

Comment: si haces un seguimiento de tu codigo, te vas a dar cuenta

Comment: Alguna forma de llevar esos valores al config.smt??

Answer (score 0):

Agrega la libreria de envio de correos

```
using System.Net.Mail;
```

y aqui esta el codigo perfecto para enviar correos compatible con las plataformas antiguas y nuevas, feliz navidad.

```
 try
        {
            var mensaje = new MailMessage();
            mensaje.From = new MailAddress({Direccion origen});
            mensaje.Sender = new MailAddress({nombre usuario (normalmente lo mismo que lo anterior)});
            mensaje.To.Add({Direccion de destino (Puedes agregar varios destinatarios)});
            mensaje.To.Add({Direccion de destino});
            mensaje.To.Add({Direccion de destino});
            mensaje.Subject = {Asunto del correo};
            mensaje.Body = {Cuerpo del correo};
            mensaje.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            mensaje.IsBodyHtml = true;
            using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient({Tu servidor de correo}, {Puerto de tu servidor}))
            {
                var creds = new NetworkCredential({Direccion origen}, {Tu clave de correo});
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtpClient.Credentials = creds;
                if ({variable booleana si usa TLS})
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = {variable booleana si usa SSL};
                smtpClient.Send(mensaje);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
```

Ahora solo reemplaza los valores que estan entre llaves y a enviar.